# collection empty in symfony when collecting many to many datas

Tags: symfony, doctrine, many-to-many

I have two entities Template and Zone in Symfony connected by a many to many relationship.

I'm trying to get datas from one of theses so i'm using the following command

```
$templates = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Template::class)
            ->findAll();
```

I succeed to get my templates datas but the champ "zones" display an empty collection.
Have you got an idea about why I don't get the zones attached to the template.

Here are my code :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\TemplateRepository")
 */
class Template
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * Many Users have Many Groups.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Zone", inversedBy="templates")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="templates_zones")
     */
    private $zones;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $zonesNumber;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=1)
     */
    private $format;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $level;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $background;

    /**
     * Template constructor.
     * @param $zones
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->zones =  new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getZonesNumber(): ?int
    {
        return $this->zonesNumber;
    }

    public function setZonesNumber(?int $zonesNumber): self
    {
        $this->zonesNumber = $zonesNumber;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getFormat(): ?string
    {
        return $this->format;
    }

    public function setFormat(string $format): self
    {
        $this->format = $format;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getLevel(): ?int
    {
        return $this->level;
    }

    public function setLevel(int $level): self
    {
        $this->level = $level;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getBackground(): ?string
    {
        return $this->background;
    }

    public function setBackground(?string $background): self
    {
        $this->background = $background;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Zone[]
     */
    public function getZones(): Collection
    {
        return $this->zones;
    }

    public function addZone(Zone $zone): self
    {
        if (!$this->zones->contains($zone)) {
            $this->zones[] = $zone;
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeZone(Zone $zone): self
    {
        if ($this->zones->contains($zone)) {
            $this->zones->removeElement($zone);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And the zone Entity

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ZonesRepository")
 */
class Zone
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * Many Groups have Many Users.
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Template", mappedBy="zones")
     */
    private $templates;

    /**
     * Zone constructor.
     * @param $templates
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->templates = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|Template[]
     */
    public function getTemplates(): Collection
    {
        return $this->templates;
    }

    public function addTemplate(Template $template): self
    {
        if (!$this->templates->contains($template)) {
            $this->templates[] = $template;
            $template->addZone($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeTemplate(Template $template): self
    {
        if ($this->templates->contains($template)) {
            $this->templates->removeElement($template);
            $template->removeZone($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know it's empty? do you `dump` the zones property? if so, read up on lazy loaded collections ;o)

Comment: In addition to Jakumi: Lazy loading is the custom behavior for relations in doctrine. It means that the collection will be loaded with an additional query when needed thus only when you access it. Place your dump command after you accessed the data from te related entities and you will find it

Comment: thank you so much. i used fetch eager and it worked.